# Purpose of duplicating measure words?

Tags: measure-word

I came across the following sentence in New Practical Chinese Reader 2, lesson 21, paraphrasing:

南方的花园

中国人常说： “上有天堂，下有苏杭。”意思是苏州和杭州这两个城市跟天堂一样美。它们都在中国的南方，是中国南方的“花园”。它们的美在哪儿呢？－－杭州的山水和苏州的园林。苏州的园林非常有名。那些园林是过去一些有钱人请人修建的。园林里边有山，有水，有花儿，真是***一幅幅***美丽的山水画。中国的园林跟西方的园林很不一样。中国的园林好像中国画，是用水和墨画的；西方的园林好像油画，是用油彩的。因为中国古典的园林常常是画家和诗人设计的，西方的园林是建筑师设计的，所以它们的美很不一样。

I learned that 幅 is a measure word for pictures and that some verbs can be duplicated, but I don't understand the implication in this context.

My Chinese friend says it can also be done for other measure words such as 一张张 but she couldn't explain why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**重叠量词** (repetitive classifiers) are used to indicate:

- every, or;
- one by one, or;
- abundance.

> 除了计量名量词外，不少量词可以重叠使用。例如：名量词：个个/件件/张张。动量词：次次/趟趟/回回。
>
> 量词重叠还有一种形式是 “一XX” 如 “一个个” “一件件”
>   “一趟趟”，这种形式表示的语法意义有和上面的重叠形式相同的，也有不同的。意义有三种：
>
> 1. 表示“每一”。基本同 “XX” 重叠式。小伙子们一**个个**身强力壮。
> 2. 表示“逐一”。表示此种意义的重叠形式作状语。我们要一**件件**仔细检查，不要漏掉。
> 3. 表示“多”。他一**次次**给我打电话。

Source http://www.china001.com/show_hdr.php?dname=6FA0G51&xpos=132

---

This is how I would interpret the particular sentence in your question,

> 园林里边有山，有水，有花儿，真是**一幅幅**美丽的山水画。

Within the forest garden, there are hills, rivers and flowers; a picturesque view from **every** angle.

Comment: So how would you translate it in this case? "It's indeed beautiful as every landscape painting?"

Comment: Here it's the first case, meaing "each". In your case, it means "Each of the gardens is like a beautiful landscape painting". Note that in the previous sentence,  the subject is "那些园林", which means "these gardens".

Comment: 非常感谢. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

one reason for using duplicate measure words is to emphasis. But in this case, using "一幅幅" is a bit different from "一幅". "一幅" implies "一幅画园林的画，其中有山有水有花", and "一幅幅" means "一副画山的画，一幅画水的画，一幅画花的画".

Comment: Not necessarily; 一幅幅 could also imply that each of the 画 contains 山, 水, or 花.